# Why is SimpleImputer's fit_transform not working for dataframe in google colab?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory

```
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent')
weather_test = imp.fit_transform(weather_test)
```

The above code is throwing error in google colab when weather_test is a pandas dataframe.
But when I change weather_test to numpy array, it works.

```
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent', verbose=0)
weather_test = imp.fit_transform(np.array(weather_test))
```

Comment: Do you mind to add the full error?

Answer (score 0):

Scikit-learn's API methods generally assume the input will be a numpy array rather than a pandas dataframe. For an example of how to use this functionality with a dataframe, see [How to use sklearn fit_transform with pandas and return dataframe instead of numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35723472/how-to-use-sklearn-fit-transform-with-pandas-and-return-dataframe-instead-of-num)