# bad input shape when using labelEncoder

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a fairly large dataframe with both numerical and categorical values. I'm trying to encode the categorical values but am getting the above error.

Here's a simple version of the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(LabelEncoder)
# Encoding the variable
fit = df[catgoricalValues].apply(lambda x: d[x.name].fit_transform(df[catgoricalValues]))
```

I'm using the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35724176/640558), except instead of applying it on the entire dataframe, I specified the columns to encode.

I get this error:

```
ValueError: bad input shape (490546, 11)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Label encoding across multiple columns in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458645/label-encoding-across-multiple-columns-in-scikit-learn)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Seems like you are trying to apply the LabelEncoder to multiple columns;
While you can [apply the same LabelEncoder to all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458645/label-encoding-across-multiple-columns-in-scikit-learn);

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

encoded = df[categoricalVal].apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
```

It it better to use a new encoder for each columns. The link above should provide you with the solution.

Comment: I received the same error - ValueError: bad input shape (490546, 11)

Comment: Thank you for the update. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do? I just have a list of categorical values and I want to encode them all(then reverse the encoding later). 

When I ran your code I got this error - TypeError: argument must be a string or number

Comment: Okay, can you provide a small example of your dataset?