# df columns saling ERRORCODE

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hey i try to scale my df with different datatypes. I already changed the float64 into integer64 format.. but it keeps giving me the error:

`TypeError: The DTypes <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'> and <class 'numpy.dtype[int64]'> do not have a common DType. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is` object`.`.

the dataset consists of: [Columns with DType][1]

I want to scale the data with this Code:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
```

df_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(df)
df_scaled.shape

as soon a i run it it gives me the error
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EllTf.png

Comment: Does the error come when you attempt to convert the float64 column datatype to integer64?

Comment: no the error starts when i do the following (edited the code)

Comment: Have you viewed this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35723472/how-to-use-sklearn-fit-transform-with-pandas-and-return-dataframe-instead-of-num? It discusses converting the dataframe to a numpy array using as_matrix(), and then scaling.