# TypeError: fit_transform() missing argument: y when using ColumnTransformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have two pipelines, one for my categorical features and one for my numeric features, that I feed into my column transformer. I then what to be able to fit the column transformer on my dataframe so I can see what it looks like.

My code is as follows:

```
num_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('impute', RandomSampleImputer()),
    ('scale',MinMaxScaler())
])
cat_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('impute', RandomSampleImputer()),
    ('target',TargetEncoder())
])

col_trans = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('num_pipeline',num_pipeline,num_cols),
    ('cat_pipeline',cat_pipeline,cat_cols)
    ],remainder=drop)
```

When I run

```
df_transform=col_trans.fit(df)
```

I get the error:

```
raise TypeError('fit_transform() missing argument: ''y''')'
```

Why is this?

Comment: Some pipelines need the response variable to calculate the transformations. Perhaps its the case of one of the members of the pipeline?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I am using TargetEncoder() and that requires the target feature. I am still struggling to view my transformed dataset. When I run X_transformed=preprocessor.fit(X,y) I no longer get an error, but printing X_transformed does not show me the transformed dataframe. How can I see that?

Comment: You may want to do `X_transformed = preprocessor.fit_transform(X,y)` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Guilherme Marthe and Luca Anzalone have pointed out, some transformers such as `TargetEncoder` do indeed require the target variable `y` to calculate the transformations.

In order to get your transformed dataset, you need to call `fit_transform()` on your `ColumnTransformer` `col_trans`, passing both `X` (your features) and `y` (your target).

When you call `fit_transform()`, the `fit()` method will first calculate any parameters needed for the transformation (such as the mean and standard deviation for normalization), and then `transform()` will apply the transformations to your data. The result is a new dataset where the transformations have been applied.

To ensure your output is a `pandas` `DataFrame`, you can use the `set_config()` function from `scikit-learn` to change the global configuration:

```
from sklearn import set_config
set_config(transform_output="pandas")
```

Now, when you transform your data, the output will be a `pandas` `DataFrame`:

```
X_transformed = col_trans.fit_transform(X, y)
```

Note that `X_transformed` is now a `DataFrame` with the column names preserved.

[Please remember to update `scikit-learn` to version 1.2 or later to use this feature.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35723472/how-to-use-sklearn-fit-transform-with-pandas-and-return-dataframe-instead-of-num/74733267#74733267)